# SQL Server of wamp is blocked because of Avast

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've installed Avast! Premier 2014 on my PC today, and the localhost just won't work! The program just cannot access the database. I'm sure it's because the Avast! because earlier today without the Avast! It worked perfectly fine.

Does anyone else had this problem and he managed to solve it? I simply just can not program anything until its solved.

EDIT:

If I turn off avast completely, it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Solution(s) for this, found in the official wampserver.com forums:

SOLUTION #1:

This problem is caused by Windows (7) in combination with any software that also uses port 80 (like Skype or IIS (which is installed on most developer machines)). A video solution can be found here (34.500+ views, damn, this seems to be a big thing ! EDIT: The video now has ~60.000 views ;) )

To make it short: open command line tool, type "netstat -aon" and look for any lines that end of ":80". Note thatPID on the right side. This is the process id of the software which currently usesport 80. Press AltGr + Ctrl + Del to get into the Taskmanager. Switch to the tab where you can see all services currently running, ordered by PID. Search for that PID you just notices and stop that thing (right click). To prevent this in future, you should config the software's port settings (skype can do that).

SOLUTION #2:

left click the wamp icon in the taskbar, go to apache > httpd.conf and edit this file: change "listen to port ....  80" to 8080. Restart. Done !

SOLUTION #3:

Port 80 blocked by "Microsoft Web Deployment Service", simply deinstall this, more info here

By the way, it's not Microsoft's fault, it's a stupid usage of ports by most WAMP stacks.

IMPORTANT: you have to use localhost or 127.0.0.1 now with port 8080, this means 127.0.0.1:8080 or localhost:8080.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not the kind of problem I'm having. It doesn't matter what port I'm using, AVAST! firewall just blocks wamp

Answer (score 0):

May be for 2 reasons -
1). Bcoz Of Avast - If that so then fist stop avast service temparaly then try.
2). Otherwise Just uninstall again avast then try, may be because of your port issue or something else

Comment: I've mentioned that it happens because of avast, the question is how I make avast not do it